# Serif font identification

Tags: font-identification, serif

I am looking for the name of the font in the picture.

Any idea will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Btw, I have closely observed and matched it with **Times New Roman** but its not that(Some of the serifs do not match). Feel free to verify anyway. Also, its a high res image so you can take a really closer look.

Comment: When zooming close, some letters look really odd in this shot which makes me wonder how it was captured. Especially the lowercase u (i.e. in fulfillment) look off the baseline and too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, it is [bookman-old-style](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bookman-old-style/) font

[image]

or some of [CASLON](http://www.myfonts.com/search/CASLON/fonts/)s fonts -

[image]

Comment: No, I guess not. Observe the alphabet 'C', it has a serif at the bottom tail in Caslon while 'C' in my picture has not."Probably, it is some of CASLONs fonts" : I need the complete set.Its really important

Comment: @pulp_fiction  adobe caslon has similar C, but anyway caslon seems to be pretty close http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/adobe-caslon/

Comment: Right, it is! but just askin, the normal caslon and Adobe Caslon are different right? And did Adobe create Caslon(all of them)?

Comment: Its not Adobe Caslon exactly!!. You really had me believing, I mean they are really close indeed!

Comment: @pulp_fiction there are thousands of caslon-like fonts :)

Comment: Pardon, I am new to the font world and yeah that's true that there are thousands of fonts like that. So you suggest that this is just some custom made font? But I got this certificate from an institute and its really doubtful that they would go to this extent to prevent extraction of font, to use a custom font. They could have just used Times New Roman or any standard font.

Comment: @pulp_fiction http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/bookman-old-style/

Comment: Yeah, probably that makes sense. That's a standard font. But thanks that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

More exactly, it looks like ITC Bookman to me

[image: ITC Bookman Demi][image: ITC Bookman Roman]

Comment: No, I guess not. Observe the alphabets 'a' and 'c' carefully. The serif of 'a' is curvy at the baseline in ITC bookman but that's not the case with my text(mine is touching the baseline). Also the letter 'c' serif at the top turns at a different angle (almost right angle) than what is in my text.(http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/bookman/) View at full zoom